# Running applicaition but nothing is appearing

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I have been running my project using F5, it says Ready and then nothing happens.  It goes it debugging mode )Play button is disabled, pause and stop are enabled) but my application does not appear.

Could you advise me what is the problem?

Thanks
Fuqna

Comment: Too generic. Is a Windows Forms application? did you set up a startup object like the main form or is there any breakpoint set?

Comment: It is a Windows Forms application.  It was running fine before I made some changes to the code.  Startup project is there, as before and breakpoints have been removed.  Despite all this, issue is still there.

Comment: So, erm, **what changes did you make to the code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infinite loop ...  maybe... on startup form.load event ?